# What preposition after "take me"? Are there any other synonyms too?

Tags: american-english, spoken-english

My skin has started tanning. What do I say about people's reaction to me?

> Now they take me **as** [an] Indian
>   Now they take me **for** [an] Indian

What do I add here after **take me**?

Comment: Given that _take_ has more than 50 meanings, I'm not sure why it would be obvious to a learner which preposition comes after "take me". This seems like a legitimate learner's question and I'm confused about the close votes.

Answer (score 3):

If you are not an Indian, but just look like one because of your tan, it might be better to say:

> Now they *mis*take me for an Indian.

If you wanted to use *take* instead of *mistake*, I would say it like this:

> Now they take me **to be** an Indian.

The phrase "takes me to be" is roughly equivalent to "regards me as" or "believes I am." This fits along with Definition #21 at [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/take):

> **take** (*verb*) To assume or suppose; to reckon; to regard or consider : *Do you take me for a fool?‎  Do you take me to be stupid?‎*

Here's a quote using this construct, taken from literature:

> ...you shall see that I am not the vanquished Don Quixote you take me to be.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an appropriate reference for this usage:

> What do you take me for? - [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/what-do-you-take-me-for)

This means "What sort of person do you think I am?" For example, "What do you take me for, an idiot?" This expression dates from the mid-1800s.

> Take me **as** I am - Bod Dylan song title

In this example, **take** means **accept**.

> no one would take me **as** a client - [I made it this far](https://books.google.com.eg/books?id=VJqZjaRZKYQC&pg=PA43&dq=%22take%20me%20as%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiss9Wlvs_OAhWHrRoKHXBrCQUQ6AEITDAJ#v=onepage&q=%22take%20me%20as%22&f=false)

In this example, **take** means [accept as a job or responsibility](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/take-sth-on).

Here are lots more references to [take me as](https://www.google.com.eg/search?q=%22take%20me%20as%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=cr&ei=0wi4V8rsN8TlUfWEkOAB).